# How to trouble shoot and found root cause of error based on Co-relation id found in error message

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, error-handling, windows-server-2012-r2

I have two WFE servers for our SharePoint 2013 farm and i get some errors and i found a co-relation ID

1. so for trace this error from which WFE server i start the troubleshoot?
2. is this corelation ID is same in both WFE servers logs in 15 folder?

Answer (score 1):

Correlation ID is same across all server in the farm. In order to get the complete trace of the correlation ID, You should use the below powershell.

```
Merge-SPLogFile -Correlation -Path "C:\Logs\FarmMergedLog.log"
```

Above [command](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff607721.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) will Combines trace log entries from all farm computers into a single log file on the local computer.

Comment: and before that we should enable verbose logging, how it can be useful for trace errors?

Comment: Enabling verbose logging will give you more granular level detail...verbose logging always helpfull in order to troubleshoot.